# Stringify a key value pair in Javascript and session storage

Tags: javascript, json, sessionstorage

I have code as follows:

```
var employee = {};

employee["fullname"] = document.userForm.fullname.value;
employee["license"] = document.userForm.license.value;
employee["address"] = document.userForm.address.value;
employee["dob"] = document.userForm.dob.value;
employee["city"] = document.userForm.city.value;
employee["state"] = document.userForm.state.value;
employee["zip"] = document.userForm.zip.value;
employee["sex"] = document.userForm.sex.value;

sessionStorage.setItem("session", JSON.stringify({"employees": [employee]}));
```

Is it correct to store it this way? Also if this is correct , how do I retrieve the information using `getItem`?

Answer (score 1):

retrieve it with      :

```
 var mySessionData = sessionStorage.getItem("session");
 var mySessionDataParsed = JSON.parse( mySessionData );
```

*edit*

> Is it correct to store it this way

```
 //sessionStorage.setItem("session", JSON.stringify({"employees": [employee]}));
 sessionStorage.setItem("session", JSON.stringify( employee ) );
 // this way is suffisant ! 
 // but if you prefer an array you can go with your way too !
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dot and/or bracket notation.

```
sessionStorage["session"] = JSON.stringify({"employees": [employee]});
// or
sessionStorage.session = JSON.stringify({"employees": [employee]});
```

and the same goes for the right hand side of an assignment.

```
data = sessionStorage["session"];
// or
data = sessionStorage.session;
```

No need to invoke the get and set item methods as you just add needless overhead.